# Need help understanding ∃x∀y vs ∀x∃y

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

My understanding is that for ∃x∀y, there can only be one x value that is true for every single y value. Meaning theres only one x value (which cannot be changed) for every single different y value. The statement ∃x∀y(p(x,y)) is true when there is one x value (lets say x=0) that is true for y=-2,-1,0,1,2,... (for every single y). Correct me if I am wrong but this is my understanding of this notation.

And now my understanding for the second notation ∀x∃y(p(x,y)) is that for every x value, there exists a y such that p(x,y). Meaning for every x value (x=-2,-1,0,1,2,...) there can be a different y value for each x value so that the statement is true.

I dont really know how to explain this well but I'll try to summarize my understanding. If the notation is ∃x∀y then theres only one x that cannot be changed that is true for every y. If the notation is ∀x∃y then the y value doesnt have to be the same y value for every x value. Meaning for every x value there can be a y value that is different than another y value for another x value.

If my thinking is correct then please say so otherwise please try and help me understand this.

Comment: Almost correct : $\exists x$ means that there is at least one x, not exactly one.

Comment: @amWhy Wouldn't $\exists x\forall y(L(x,y))$ mean that one person loves everyone, not that they are loved by everyone?

Comment: For every lock there is a key, but there's not a key that opens every lock.

Comment: It'll be more clear if you know a concept called [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property). Your first mixed quantifier has such a strong property like a well ordered finite set with a terminal object, while the latter has not (such as the common infinit $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Intuitive examples:
∀x∃y: every human has a father.
∃x∀y: there exists a father of all humans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, with the following remark.

For $\exists x \forall y: p(x,y)$, your phrasing is not consistent. Sometimes you say 'there can be only one', but in other cases 'there is one value'. The interpretation is the second one: there is (at least) one value for $x$ such that $p(x,y)$ for all $y$. The same $x$ for all $y$, you're right there and that's the crucial part, but it is possible that there is an $x' \neq x$ such that also $p(x',y)$ for all $y$.

Comment: Does "∃x∀y" convey a different meaning from "∀y∃x"? I.e., is subsequent quantification treated as a dependent clause of the preceding?, or would this dependency be notated with some mathematical punctuation?  And dothe meanings differ, if whatso?

Comment: They are different meanings.  The first says there is one x that works with every y.  The second one says that for each y has an x that it works with, but it doesn't have to be the SAME x

Comment: Thank you so much. And yeah now I see the "there is at least one".

Answer (score 2):

As a side note,  the (mostly standard) notation for there exists exactly one unique thing is to add a ! to your modifier $\exists !x:p(x)$ means there exists one unique $x $ that makes $p$ true,  for example  if $p(x)$ was the statement $x+3=7$,   there does indeed exist exactly one value that makes it true, $x=4$.

We can do $\exists !$ with the existing notation, it is just shorthand notation for

$$(\exists x):[p(x) \land (\forall y):p(y)\implies x=y]$$

Without the ! you get at LEAST one.